# How to minimize upload/download amount for a reverse SSH tunnel on a Raspberry Pi with Cellular Hat?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, tunnel, network-monitoring

I have a Raspberry Pi with a Sixfab Cellular Hat that is behind a CG-NAT. I have set up a reverse SSH tunnel between my server and Raspberry Pi, but I noticed that the upload and download amounts sum up to around 26 MB per day. Is there a way to minimize the upload and download amount, or are these metrics normal for this setup?

I would appreciate any suggestions or insights on how to reduce the data usage for this configuration.
Thank you.

Currently the ssh command that I am using for the reverse ssh tunnel is this

```
ssh -nNTv -R 0.0.0.0:2237:localhost:22 user@host-ip
```

Comment: 26MB per day is barely anything. Why are you worried?

Comment: Also, are you using the terminal actively? If not, you could always just disconnect the ssh, I don’t see your issue.

Comment: I guess I was just looking for a confirmation that these amounts are in the normal range. I am not using the terminal actively and the reverse ssh tunnel is running in the background listening for the connections from my back-end service.